# Indicate in the browser tab when there is activity

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if Stack Overflow (and its brethren) visually indicated when there was activity on one's account, as, e.g., att.net/yahoo does:

[image]

That way I wouldn't have to interrupt my work to check it, I could just glance up and see.

Comment: Well, if you call that an answer; that's like asking for a glass of milk and being handed a bucket and pointed to the barn.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon still, this is duplicate request.

Comment: Also note that question listings already change the title to notify you of new questions.